# Incorrect syntax near ( SQL Update command)

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

Seems a simple syntax error but need help.

```
protected void editback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String EditStoryID = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value;
    String EditProjectID = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    String EditRequirement = TextBoxBacklog.Text;
    String EditLock = "0";

    String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ScrumString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


    myConnection.Open();
    String query = "UPDATE product_backlog SET (project_id=@project_id,user_story=@user_story,is_locked=@is_locked) WHERE project_backlog.id = (@id)";

    SqlCommand commandEdit = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
    commandEdit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_id", EditProjectID);
    commandEdit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", EditStoryID);
    commandEdit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_story", EditRequirement);
    commandEdit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@is_locked", EditLock);

    commandEdit.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);

    Labelsuccess.Text = "User story has been updated";
    TextBoxBacklog.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: in your query try removing ( and ) in the set and also around @id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` clause should not be surrounded by parentheses:

```
UPDATE product_backlog
    SET project_id = @project_id,
        user_story = @user_story,
        is_locked = @is_locked
   WHERE project_backlog.id = (@id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the parentheses after the SET statement.
They are excepted after the WHERE statement but the SET must be without, even if you have more than 1 field you want to update

```
UPDATE your_table SET key=@value WHERE id = (@id)
```